# Formula for forking?

Tags: operating-system, fork, formula, recurrence

Is there a closed form to count the total number of processes after `n` forks ? For example, for something like:

```
int main() 
{
 fork();
 fork();
 fork();
}
```

I came up with the formula `n(n+1)/2 + n-1`. When `n = 3`, as in above, the correct of answer of `8` comes. Is this formula correct ?

Comment: ...but obviously not correct for n=1

Comment: Indeed, a rather simple problem I was mixed up with !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if OS terminology is misused here, I'll use 'intuitive' words for the case.

Each and every fork creates two processes out of one. Thus one can think of single `fork` as `+2 -1`.

Thinking of it the other way we'll come to conclusion that after `n` `forks` have been done in all processes (according to program flow) and right before each and every resulting process calls `exit` syscall there is complete binary tree with `n` levels with each leaf representing a process. Thus, processes count will be equal to `2^n`.

Here is a simple illustration (blank rects --- old processes, green rects --- processes right before call to `_exit`):
[image]